# Should I create multiple hiredis objects?

Tags: redis, hiredis

I am using Hiredis in C++ project and it works well.
One thing I still haven't figured out is:
I need to use hiredis in multiple classes, should I create Redis object in all classes? Will it cause any problem?

```
Redis m_redis;
```

Comment: hiredis has no `Redis` class. Do you wrap hiredis stuff into your own class?

Comment: @for_stack Oh, sorry, you are right.  I forgot about this part. Thank you.

Comment: @for_stack I think I should have asked "if I call redisConnect multiple times to setup multiple connections, will it be a problem?" or should I create only one connection and share it between classes?

Comment: It's safe to call `redisConnect` multiple times to create multiple connections to Redis. However, the return value, i.e. `redisContext` is not thread-safe. So I you want to share a single connection, you need a lock.

Comment: Also, you can try [redis-plus-plus](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/), which is a production-ready, thread-safe (unless otherwise stated) C++ client for Redis based on hiredis. *Declaimer*: I'm the author of this library.